Knapsack with both upper and lower capacity
In the usual knapsack problem, there are $n$ items with values $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ and costs $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ and a total budget $B$, and the goal is to select a subset of items with maximum total value among those subsets with total cost at most $B$. This problem is NP-hard, but it has an FPTAS.
In my problem, in addition to an upper bound $B$, there is also a lower bound $L$; the goal is to select a subset of items with maximum total value among those subsets with total cost at least $L$ and at most $B$.
Is anything known about polynomial-time approximation algorithms to this problem?
